# Getting the namespace of the file that called a function in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

If I have the following file:

```
<?php
namespace SampleProject;

hello_world();
```

and this in a separate file:

```
<?php
function hello_world() {

}
```

Is there anyway for the `hello_world()` function to get the namespace of the file that called it (So `SampleProject`)

Comment: Since one file can contain several namespaces, that seems like a misguided question. What problem are you really trying to solve with this?

Comment: [What is the XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/164291)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do with that namespace information, but you could add a parameter to the function and then call it like this:

```
hello_world(__NAMESPACE__);
```

read more about the `__NAMESPACE__` constant in the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php).

Adding `__NAMESPACE__` inside your function will simply give an empty string since your function is not inside of a namespace.